# Check if JSON containts node with value

Tags: java, json, jsonpath

I have Java application which gets JSON strings like this one

```
{
    "name": "testName",
    "message": [
        "TestMessage."
    ]
}
```

What I need is to check if there is a "message" array node which has value of "TestMessage." in any of it's elements.

I have access to com.jway.jsonpath.JsonPath in my code. But it looks that it can only read value of particular node. E.g. like this I will be able to fetch first element of "message" array

```
JsonPath.read(content, "$.message[0]")
```

But in this way I will have to fetch all elements of the array into Java and validate them there.
Instead I would like to perform this check by JsonPath engine itself.

How can I achive this goal with JsonPath? Is it better to use other library?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the filter operations.

> Filters are logical expressions used to filter arrays. A typical filter would be [?(@.age > 18)] where @ represents the current item being processed. More complex filters can be created with logical operators && and ||. String literals must be enclosed by single or double quotes ([?(@.color == 'blue')] or [?(@.color == "blue")]).

like this:

```
 JsonPath.read(json, "$.message[?(@ == "TestMessage.")]");
```

more can refer the readme.MD of https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I can see it works here https://jsonpath.herokuapp.com/. But it does not work in my app and here https://jsonpath.curiousconcept.com/. The verion of json-path I am using is 2.0.0. Do you know if I should use any specific version? Or what can be the reason why it is not working?

Comment: Ok, I switched to latest jway version which is 2.4.0 at it works now. Thanks a lot for help!